# How to call a method in dependency jar from java script

Tags: javascript, java, ajax

I have a jar dependency in my java script project. I have to call a method in the 
jar present under `WEB-INF/lib/example.jar` from the java script file.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you mean JavaScript and not Java?

Comment: `Java` is not `Javascript`! Please, specify more details.

Comment: The question is a bit broad (and unclear to me btw). You should take the time to explain your requirement, include all the relevant source code and tell us what you tried and why it doesn't work

Comment: Can people stop editing the question until we're sure the OP's not actually trying to use javascript?

Answer (score 0):

It used to be possible to execute java code on the client side (browser) with `Java Applets` but this stuff is no longer supported by browsers. You need either write your code in `Javascript` or use Ajax to make asynchronous calls to the Backend.

```
function myReq() 
{
  try
  {
    var myJSONObject = {"data1":"some data"};
    var toServer = myJSONObject.toJSONString();
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", "[your_server]/[servlet_name]", true);
    request.send(toServer);
    return true;
  } catch(err) {
    alert(err.message);
  }  
}
```

Comment: `It used to be possible to execute java code on the client side (browser) with Java Applets` -  Are you sure? Applets are a client-side feature, AFAIK they can't directly communicate with the server and use libraries stored in the server.

Comment: Yes, so what's wrong with what i said. I did not say that java applets allowed you to make calls the server side. I said Applets allowed you to execute Java code on client side ie browsers. By that i mean the jar as a direct dependency in your applet!

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes, the OP seems to be talking about server-side libraries, that's why I asked, but we have way too few informations to know for sure. Let's wait for an update.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to add much more detailed information. I suppose when you say Javascript project, you are referring to a NodeJS project. In that case you could use `child_process` (https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) module to run a shell command to execute a static method from the jar: `java -classpath path-to-jar <package>.<classname>`